# How to define an efficient lookup table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-select-db

I want to create a table that will act as a lookup table for an application.
The format I have in mind is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Associations (
  obj_id int unsigned NOT NULL,
  attr_id int unsigned NOT NULL,
  assignment Double NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (`obj_id`, `attr_id`),
);
```

Anyway I have the following question:
The idea is that this table will be loaded/used in the application level as a map:
`obj_id -> listof(<attr_id, assignment>)`

The `obj_id` refers to another table which is huge. Now this means that `Associations` will be `x times` the original table since we'll have multiple rows for each `obj_id`.
Taking into account that I don't really need to SELECT in the table by `assignment` and at this point I also don't need to SELECT by `attr_id` is there another design approach for the table that could be more efficient?

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean by SEARCH in thi context

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I meant is `SELECT` I updated the post

Comment: Still a little confused. I assume this is a simple cross reference (link table) so if you have a obj_id you can find the associated attr_id(s) and if you have a attr_id you can find the associated obj_id(s). So if you dont need to select on assignment or addr_id then all you have is a table of obj_id's which you already have in the HUGE table but I hope as they are indexed on obj_id I am lost as to the use of this cross reference table

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I need to SELECT/retrieve all the `attr/assigments` for each `obj_id`. The `attr_id` and `assigmnent` do not refer to any other table. It is data stored associated per `obj_id`

Comment: Not data that also exists in the huge table I hope

Comment: @RiggsFolly: No they don't exist in the huge table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I was thinking to e.g. store per `obj_id` a json object for the list of `<attr_id, assignment>` per `obj_id` but I am not sure if that is a good way either

Comment: well if all you need to do is `SELECT attr_id, unsigned WHERE obj_id = ` then its fine, and you only really need to index the obj_id

Comment: Be very careful with JSON, it fine for data thats only ever retrieved, but as soon as you want to query based on the existance of something in the JSON, its gets overly complicated

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yes I would only need to do `SELECT obj_id, attr_id, assignment WHERE obj_id IN (.....large number of values)` to create the mapping in the application. The fact that the table will have a huge number of rows made me think if there is a problem with this approach